# How to pass Java variable value in td tag of html

Tags: java, html

String TC_Status="PASS";

How to pass TC_Status value "PASS" in td tag of html

```
  File f = new File("source.htm");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        bw.write("<html>");
        bw.write("<body>");
        bw.write("<table cellspacing="+50+">");
        bw.write("<tr>");
        bw.write("<td>S.No</td>");
        bw.write("<td>TestCaseDescription</td>");
        bw.write("<td>Status</td>");
        bw.write("<td>Screenshot</td>");
        bw.write("</tr>");

        bw.write("<tr>");
        bw.write("<td>1</td>");
        bw.write("<td>Login</td>");
        bw.write("<td></td>");     ---------------------------------- HERE PASS is to be displayed

        bw.write("<td></td>");      
        bw.write("</tr>");

        bw.write("</table>");
        bw.write("</body>");
        bw.write("</html>");
        bw.close();
```

please help in getting this done

Comment: Does `bw.write("<td>");bw.write(TC_Status);bw.write("</td>");` works?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
bw.write("<td>"+TC_Status+"</td>");
```

Comment: this would work if TC_Status would have been an attribute of td tag.. but thats not the case TC_Status is a user defined variable in java whose value is PASS and that I need to pass inside html

Comment: did you try my suggestion? this is very basic string concatenation. 'TC_Status' as a string will not be inside HTML, instead its value 'PASS' will be written.

Comment: If that doesn't work there may be a larger issue at play, as @lostsource says this is very basic stuff.

Comment: i tried your suggestion , it will print TC_Status text not its value

Comment: just in case, did you write bw.write("<td>TC_Status</td>") ?